# How come I can convert T[] to IEnumerable<T> get an error trying to convert Task<T[]> to Task<IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've that a C# array implements IEnumerable so the compiler has no complaints converting:

```
string[] array = new string[1];
IEnumerable<string> collection = array;
```

However when I have both wrapped in tasks, I get an error. Why is this not possible?

```
Task<string[]> arrayTask = Task.FromResult(new string[1]);
Task<IEnumerable<string>> collectionTask = arrayTask;
```

Here's the compile error I get (where T is the type):

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T[]>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>>
```

Comment: One more time: a box of apples is not a box of fruit. Why not? Because you can put a banana into a box of fruit, but if you put a banana into a box of apples, it is not a box of apples anymore. Therefore those two types are different, even though an apple is a fruit.

Comment: Well I'm looking at some docs for a library and I'm confused because they are returning a Task<T[]> in a method where the return type is a Task<IEnumberable<T>>

Comment: Well then the documentation is probably wrong; report the bug in the documentation if you feel like it ought to be addressed.